# Reversing the words in a sentence using Stack

Tags: java

Does my reverse method only work if I input a series of words all at once?

My task was to: Write a complete method that reads a series of Strings from the user. The user enters "end" to stop inputting words. Then, output the Strings in reverse order of how they were entered. Do not output the String “end”.
Use a stack to accomplish this task. Invoke only the methods push, pop, peek, and isEmpty on the stack object.

Here is how it is supposed to run:

```
Enter a word or 'end' to quit: Hello
Enter a word or 'end' to quit: Java
Enter a word or 'end' to quit: World
Enter a word or 'end' to quit: end
You entered (in reverse):
World
Java
Hello
```

But mine runs:

```
Enter a word or 'end' to quit: Hello
Enter a word or 'end' to quit: Java
Enter a word or 'end' to quit: World
Enter a word or 'end' to quit: end
You entered (in reverse): end
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Stack1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input = "end";
    do {
    System.out.printf("Enter a word or 'end' to quit: ");
    input = scanner.nextLine();

    if (input == null || input.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid! Try again...");
        return;
    }
    } while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("end"));
    String reverse = reverse(input);
    System.out.printf("You entered (in reverse): %s", reverse);
} 

private static String reverse(String inputString) {
    String[] str = inputString.trim().split(Pattern.quote(" "));
    Stack stack = new Stack();

    for(String input : str) {
        stack.push(input);
    }

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while( !stack.isEmpty()) {
        builder.append(stack.pop()).append(" ");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

}
```

Comment: it seems you're overwriting your `input` variable at each iteration of the do while loop. you'll need to keep a record of the `String` values already entered though I wouldn't recommend concatenating strings inside a loop, rather use a `StringBuilder` then convert to `String` when calling your _reverse_ method.

Comment: Why is everyone suggesting that the OP concatenate the strings? That is wrong. Each entered word should be added to the stack in the loop and that's it.

Comment: @TimurA. Because the original question included an implementation of `reverse()` that expects a single string with words delimited by spaces. I'm not sure why OP vandalized their own post.

Comment: @shmosel I know it was there, but I thought we are supposed to help them to make it better, not support a correct but a bad implementation

Comment: @TimurA. That's why I added the alternative solution in my answer.

Comment: If you say so, but it seems the question was pretty clear _use a stack_.

Comment: @TimurA. It does use a stack, after concatenating and splitting the string.

Comment: @shmosel and what is the point of the stack after concatenating and splitting the string?

Comment: @TimurA. To reverse the input...?

Comment: @shmosel interesting. I would have traversed the split string array in a reverse order

Comment: @TimurA. Sure, that would work. But as you pointed out, the requirement was to use a stack. OP's approach was a little convoluted, but not wrong per se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is overwriting `input` on each iteration. To make it work with your `reverse()` method, you'll want to concat each word incrementally with a space:

```
String input = "";
while (true) {
    System.out.printf("Enter a word or 'end' to quit: ");
    String next = scanner.nextLine();

    if (next == null || next.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid! Try again...");
        return;
    }

    if (next.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) {
        break;
    }

    input += next + " ";
}
```

Alternatively, you can populate the stack directly in the loop and skip the string splitting:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();

    while (true) {
        System.out.printf("Enter a word or 'end' to quit: ");
        String next = scanner.nextLine();

        if (next == null || next.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid! Try again...");
            return;
        }

        if (next.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) {
            break;
        }

        stack.push(next);
    }

    System.out.println("You entered (in reverse):");

    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
    }
}
```

Note that the latter solution correctly reverses multi-word inputs, whereas the concatenation approach can't differentiate between lines and words.

Comment: In this case,your output just in one line .is not three line

Comment: @wylasr That's a (easily fixed) technicality in OP's `reverse()` implementation; I didn't think it was worth dwelling on. My second solution does print correctly.

Answer (score 1):

1. read input.
2. push it in stack.
3. if input equals "end" then stop reading input.
4. pop stack until stack gets empty.
   **Code**

   ```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Stack;

     public class Stack1 {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

         String input = "";
         Stack stack = new Stack();
         while(true){
             System.out.printf("Enter a word or 'end' to quit: ");
             input = in.next(); // to read a word use next() method.
             if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("end")){ break; }
             if(!input.equals("")) stack.push(input);
         }
         System.out.println("You entered (in reverse): ");
         while(!stack.isEmpty())
             System.out.println(stack.pop());
        } 
     }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`String reverse = reverse(input);//input="end"`
  the problem comes from this place

@Toby Speight thanks for your advice.

by the way I am a English newcomer,I'm pleased to accept any suggestion.
What I'm trying to say is to learn debug your program when you meet problems.In this case: you want the program print a reversed String to the console .but you got a strange answer.now you need to consider where the answer maybe comes from ?
and then just print it before you use it like below

```
String reverse = reverse(input);//we said you think the problem comes from this place.
System.out.printf("%s%n",input);//this is a key statement to debug--just print it
```

Now you and then consider where `input` is not what you want? and then just consider where `input` comes from?keep on doing this ,and then you can find where
your problem comes from.

On the other hand ,there have a lot of method to debug,you can use IDE debug your program and it will be more efficient ,what's more you can use a log file and so on.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is because  your input variable contains only "end". Thus whenever you call reverse function ,it only reverses end String.

Answer (score -1):

You're using a `do-while` loop, which is why "end" gets added to the array.

To reverse the string, you can either use a `for` loop and reverse it yourself:

```
StringBuilder reverseStr = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = str.size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     reverseStr.append(str[i]);
}
```

Or use something like Apache Commons Lang `StringUtils.reverse()`.

Comment: OP isn't looking to reverse a string.